# OnePlus 3: com.android.contacts/.activities.PeopleActivity not found exception

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-7.0-nougat, activitynotfoundexception, oneplusthree

I am developing an app and using one plus 3 (Android 7.0, Oxygens OS 4.0.3, API 24). PeopleActivity is called if you have more than one contact with same phone number. In my default SMS App, it opens Quick Contact so there is some problem in my app or implementation because of which it opens PeopleActivity. But I am unable to figure out what. Any pointers in right direction appreciated.

Faulty Code

```
private View.OnClickListener onImageClick(final String phNumber) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT,
                    Uri.fromParts("tel", phNumber, null));
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
}
```

LogCat

```
04-16 07:40:25.917 1364-29446/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=com.android.contacts.action.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxxxxx cmp=com.android.contacts/.activities.ShowOrCreateActivity} from uid 10151 pid 20127 on display 0
04-16 07:40:25.918 762-1076/? D/APM_AudioPolicyManager: startOutput() output 13, stream 1, session 73
04-16 07:40:25.918 762-1076/? D/AudioPolicyManagerCustom: getNewOutputDevice() selected device 2
04-16 07:40:25.918 762-1076/? D/APM_AudioPolicyManager: setOutputDevice() device 0002 delayMs 0
04-16 07:40:25.922 762-1211/? D/audio_hw_primary: out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
04-16 07:40:25.922 762-1211/? D/audio_hw_extn: audio_extn_set_anc_parameters: anc_enabled:0
04-16 07:40:25.922 762-1211/? D/audio_hw_spkr_prot: audio_extn_fbsp_set_parameters: Speaker protection disabled
04-16 07:40:25.923 762-1076/? D/APM_AudioPolicyManager: startOutput()--
04-16 07:40:25.923 762-1211/? D/audio_hw_primary: start_output_stream: enter: stream(0xe87fd000)usecase(1: low-latency-playback) devices(0x2)
04-16 07:40:25.924 762-1211/? D/audio_hw_primary: select_devices for use case (low-latency-playback)
04-16 07:40:25.924 762-1211/? D/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: )
04-16 07:40:25.924 762-1211/? I/msm8974_platform: platform_check_and_set_codec_backend_cfg:becf: afe: bitwidth 16, samplerate 48000 channels 2, backend_idx 0 usecase = 1 device (speaker)
04-16 07:40:25.924 762-1211/? D/msm8974_platform: platform_can_split_snd_device: snd_device(2) num devices(1) new_snd_devices(0)
04-16 07:40:25.924 762-1211/? I/msm8974_platform: platform_check_and_set_codec_backend_cfg: new_snd_devices[0] is 2
04-16 07:40:25.924 762-1211/? I/msm8974_platform: platform_check_codec_backend_cfg:becf: afe: bitwidth 16, samplerate 48000 channels 2, backend_idx 0 usecase = 1 device (speaker)
04-16 07:40:25.924 762-1211/? D/msm8974_platform: platform_check_codec_backend_cfg:becf: afe: playback on non-44.1-support device Configure afe to default Sample Rate(48k)
04-16 07:40:25.924 762-1211/? I/msm8974_platform: platform_check_codec_backend_cfg:becf: afe: Codec selected backend: 0 updated bit width: 16 and sample rate: 48000
04-16 07:40:25.924 762-1211/? D/audio_hw_primary: check_usecases_codec_backend:becf: force routing 0
04-16 07:40:25.924 762-1211/? D/audio_hw_primary: check_usecases_codec_backend:becf: check_usecases num.of Usecases to switch 0
04-16 07:40:25.924 762-1211/? D/hardware_info: hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = speaker
04-16 07:40:25.924 762-1211/? D/msm8974_platform: platform_can_split_snd_device: snd_device(2) num devices(0) new_snd_devices(0)
04-16 07:40:25.924 762-1211/? D/audio_hw_primary: enable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
04-16 07:40:25.924 762-1211/? I/soundtrigger: audio_extn_sound_trigger_update_device_status: device 0x2 of type 0 for Event 1, with Raise=0
04-16 07:40:25.924 474-2481/? E/ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [4, 0]
04-16 07:40:25.924 762-1211/? D/aud_dev_arbi: acquireOneDevice: device owner for device 2 is 1
04-16 07:40:25.929 762-1211/? I/audio_hw_primary: select_devices Selected apptype: 69937
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/soundtrigger: audio_extn_sound_trigger_update_stream_status: uc_id 1 of type 0 for Event 3, with Raise=0
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? I/audio_hw_utils: audio_extn_utils_send_app_type_cfg PLAYBACK app_type 69937, acdb_dev_id 15, sample_rate 48000
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? I/audio_hw_utils: audio_extn_utils_send_app_type_cfg:becf: adm: app_type 69936, acdb_dev_id 15, sample_rate 48000
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/msm8974_platform: platform_can_split_snd_device: snd_device(2) num devices(1) new_snd_devices(-403700752)
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audio_cal, acdb_id = 15, path = 0, app id = 0x11131, sample rate = 48000
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_asm_topology
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_STREAM_TOPOLOGY_ID
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_adm_topology
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_COMMON_TOPOLOGY_ID
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audtable
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_COMMON_TABLE_SIZE
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_COMMON_TABLE
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AUDPROC_CAL
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audvoltable
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_GAIN_DEP_STEP_TABLE, vol index 5
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_VOL_CAL cal type = 12
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_audstrmtable
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_STREAM_TABLE_V2
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> audstrm_cal->cal_type.cal_data.cal_size = 16
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_afe_topology
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_TOPOLOGY_ID
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> GET_AFE_TOPOLOGY_ID for adcd_id 15, Topology Id 1025e
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_afe_cal
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_COMMON_TABLE
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AFE_CAL
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_hw_delay : acdb_id = 15 path = 0
04-16 07:40:25.930 762-1211/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_AVSYNC_INFO: ACDB_CMD_GET_DEVICE_PROPERTY
04-16 07:40:25.931 762-1211/? D/audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: apply mixer and update path: low-latency-playback quat_i2s
04-16 07:40:25.931 1364-29446/? D/ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger 
04-16 07:40:25.931 762-1211/? D/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: done
04-16 07:40:25.934 762-1211/? D/msm8974_platform: platform_set_channel_map mixer_ctl_name:Playback Channel Map15
04-16 07:40:25.934 762-1211/? D/msm8974_platform: platform_set_channel_map: set mapping(1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0) for channel:2
04-16 07:40:25.936 20127-23884/in.smslite D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
04-16 07:40:25.965 21309-23885/? D/AppTracker: App Event: start
04-16 07:40:25.976 1364-3044/? E/OnePlusAppBootManager: # startActivityLocked # aInfo = null
04-16 07:40:25.976 1364-3044/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.SEARCH cmp=com.android.contacts/.activities.PeopleActivity (has extras)} from uid 10125 pid 21309 on display 0
04-16 07:40:25.977 21309-21309/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                   --------- beginning of crash
04-16 07:40:25.978 21309-21309/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.android.contacts, PID: 21309
                                                   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.contacts/com.android.contacts.activities.PeopleActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1983)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1696)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4290)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4249)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4588)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4548)
                                                       at com.android.contacts.activities.ShowOrCreateActivity.onQueryComplete(ShowOrCreateActivity.java:191)
                                                       at com.android.contacts.util.NotifyingAsyncQueryHandler.onQueryComplete(NotifyingAsyncQueryHandler.java:61)
                                                       at android.content.AsyncQueryHandler.handleMessage(AsyncQueryHandler.java:344)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6209)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
04-16 07:40:25.978 21309-21309/? D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
04-16 07:40:25.981 1364-1850/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.contacts/.activities.ShowOrCreateActivity
04-16 07:40:25.982 1364-23887/? V/MDM_DropBox: record:system_app_crash
04-16 07:40:25.984 1364-1850/? D/ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger 
04-16 07:40:25.985 1364-1850/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity in.smslite/.activity.MainActivity
04-16 07:40:25.987 1364-29445/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@a6c8de9 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@b795472
04-16 07:40:25.987 1364-1798/? D/OSTracker: OS Event: system_app_crash
04-16 07:40:25.990 762-1211/? D/audio_hw_primary: start_output_stream: exit
04-16 07:40:25.993 1364-1850/? V/WindowManager: just for Front small Window: = Window{9c90a61 u0 net.oneplus.launcher.wallpaper.BlurWallpaper}
04-16 07:40:26.005 21309-21309/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21309 SIG: 9
04-16 07:40:26.016 1364-28534/? V/WindowManager: just for Front small Window: = Window{9c90a61 u0 net.oneplus.launcher.wallpaper.BlurWallpaper}
04-16 07:40:26.018 1364-1777/? W/InputDispatcher: channel 'af18670 com.android.contacts/com.android.contacts.activities.ShowOrCreateActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
04-16 07:40:26.019 1364-1777/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'af18670 com.android.contacts/com.android.contacts.activities.ShowOrCreateActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? simply opening the stock Contacts app at a specific contact screen? Any reason you're launching the Contacts app with just the telephone number?

Comment: I want to show contact card for the user if his (or her) avatar in my app is clicked. If person is not part of contact then show a simple pop up to add that contact

Comment: do you mean this: https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/display-contact-badge.html ?

Comment: Yes, I was looking for this. Thanks :)